# MySQL random string longer than 32 characters

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a 36 character random string in MySQL using:

```
UPDATE my_table SET entity_uid = substring(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 36);
```

but the result is always a 32 character string. Is there a way to get a longer string?

Comment: What do you need this 36-character random string *for*?  It may be worth noting that the range of `MD5()` is restricted to hexadecimal characters only, which isn't as "random" as it could be.

Comment: Using `SELECT LOWER(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(18)))` should give you 36-character strings with the best randomness properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table SET entity_uid = UUID();
```

Comment: **Note:** the `UUID` function is designed to return a universally unique identifier. This isn't necessarily "random". MySQL does use a random number to generate part of the UUID on non-Linux systems, and on Linux systems without a network interface (MAC address.)

Answer (score 12):

One option would be to generate two MD5 hashes, concatenate them together (for a total of 64 hex characters), and then take the first 36 characters of that:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CONCAT(MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND())),1,36)
```

(NOTE: an MD5 hash is 128-bits; the MySQL MD5() function returns 32 hex characters.)

Comment: I tried to do something like that but got the wrong syntax so thanks for posting that solution.

Comment: great, I have generate my random string by using this command.

Comment: Instead of SUBSTR(S, 1, N), you can write LEFT(S, N). A nice side effect of using LEFT is feeling nostalgia for Commodore 64 Basic.

Answer (score 10):

If you use MySQL with version higher than 5.7.4, you can use the newly added [RANDOM_BYTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes) function:

```
 SELECT TO_BASE64(RANDOM_BYTES(40));
```

This will result in a random string such as `r633j3sfgE85f3Jz+3AEx6Xo6qPXPUZruNimhId18iy+J1qOgZyCgg==`.

Comment: This does not necessarily result in a string with a length of 40.

Comment: But `SELECT LOWER(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(20)))` instead should guarantee 40 characters.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.

According to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

> Calculates an MD5 128-bit checksum for the string. The value is
>   returned as a string of 32 hex digits, or NULL if the argument was
>   NULL. The return value can, for example, be used as a hash key. See
>   the notes at the beginning of this section about storing hash values
>   efficiently.

Comment: True - but not really an answer to the OP's question, is it?

Comment: Sorry for the noise, I found the answer:

    UPDATE my_table SET entity_uid = UUID();
 
which is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think that answers why he cant get a string longer than 32 bits using the code he provided. But yes you are right it does not provide an alternate